# scroll to particular div using jquery in all devices and browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollto

I have problem in scroll to particular div (id wise),it's works well in desktop but not working mobile devices below (768 px).

I used this code for scroll but it's not working well in mobile.

```
// Scroll based on devices width
if ($( window ).width() <= 768 ){
    $('body').animate({ 
        scrollTop: $("#current-job").offset().top 
    }, 1000);
}
else {
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#current-job").offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

Would you please give me the solution for the same ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ok so there is an issue where mobile webkit just doesn't do that.  you COULD build your own animate function and rock an update of some low level prop but let's cheat a bit here.

Scrolling the body is an issue but scrolling a div is not.  have a look at this pen.

https://codepen.io/infn8/pen/BYGvjz

This takes a single div, `#body-wrapper`, as an immediate child of the body and makes it the new window using these styles:

```
#body-wrapper{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y:auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Then you can animate the scrolling on that.  the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` is what gives the ability to flick and scroll a bunch.

then you add the following JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".scroll-bottom").click(function(event) {
        $('#body-wrapper').animate({scrollTop: $(".scroll-top").position().top}, 'fast');
    });
    $(".scroll-top").click(function(event) {
        $('#body-wrapper').animate({scrollTop: $(".scroll-bottom").position().top}, 'fast');
    });
});
```

Notice the swapping of `.offset()` for `.position()`  this is important because with the overflow in the div the `offset` becomes incorrect.  It's also important because the item you take the `position` of must have `#body-wrapper` as its *offset parent* ([more info here](https://api.jquery.com/offsetParent/)) or the calculation will be wrong.

I have made my example scrollable with two buttons and a different layout than yours so it is a *reduced test case scenario* and nothing else is in the way.  this way you can study this and extact the core concepts into your application.

a quick conversion of your original would look like this:

```
$('#body-wrapper').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $("#current-job").position().top 
}, 1000);
```

hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

The one you have in the `else` block is fine on its own.  Just reduce it all to:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#current-job").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

and it will work.  The key is animating *both* the `html` and `body` elements

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yes, But it's only working in desktop, not in mobile devices.

Comment: Wow.  Ya.  this really used to work for me.  I have done some googling and this appears to be a serious issue.  I'll keep looking a little each day until I find a solution.  

I'm going to want to do this in the future as well.